# Error on my console application "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task, console-application

I want to run Parallel processing inside my asp.net console application. i am using c# 7.1 + Visual Studio 2017

Here is my code:-

```
 class Program
    {
        static int concurrentrequests = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConcurrentRequests"]);
        static   SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: concurrentrequests);
        static int numberofrequests = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["numberofrequests"].ToString());
        static  int waitduration = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["waitdurationmilsc"].ToString());
        private static async Task<ScanInfo> gettingCustomerInfo(string website)
        {
            await throttler.WaitAsync();
            ScanInfo si = new ScanInfo();
            int counter = 1;
            try
            {
                //code goes here..
                Console.WriteLine(website + "    -->     " + si.EmailGateway + "    -->     " + si.Status);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
                try
                {
                    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) // call the PM API to get the account id 
                    {
                        //code goes here..

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {



                }
                //string pmtoken = tokenGet();

                finally
                {

                    throttler.Release();
                }

            }
            return si;
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Marketing ipfd = new Marketing();
            try
            {
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
                {
                    //code goes here..

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {


            }
            var tasks = ipfd.companies.Select(c => gettingCustomerInfo(c.properties.website.value)).ToList();
            var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }}
```

now in my above code, i am trying to call the `gettingcustomerinfo` in parallel manner. but my above code will raise the following error:-

> "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry
>   point"

now if i use :-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

instead of :-

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
```

i will get this error instead:-

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider
>   marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return
>   type to 'Task'.

on:-

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

so can anyone advice on this please?

Comment: C#'s async-await is more about concurrency than parallelism , it's best for IO-bound tasks which don't normally need threads for parallel because OS could handle that, for cpu tasks I prefer using Thread pools

Comment: and notice that CLR chooses whether the `await`ed function should be called on a separate thread or the current thread so it's an implementation detail

Comment: @niceman by parallel i mean that i need to call the `gettingcustomerinfo` method multiple times at the same time.. not sure if this is called parallel or concurrency?.. and my `getingcustomerinfo` do 2 main tasks, 1) It will call an external web service using `WebClient` + 2) call some internal libraries to get the email hosting address based on the IP address using .net library called `ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns` .. so can i know what is your comments on my appraoch?

Comment: this question explains the difference between parallelism and concurrency https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190719/the-difference-between-concurrent-and-parallel-execution

Comment: anyway `gettingcustomerinfo` is doing IO-tasks so async-await is best for it, but don't assume that if you don't see any new threads created that those operations aren't run concurrently

Comment: @niceman ok thanks for the link and the info.. so you mean my appraoch should be fine,, is this correct?

Comment: yes this is correct ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use C# 7.2 in your VisualStudio proj?

You must use C# 7.2 or latest version to build the async main.

Try to right click your project and click the property button. And then you should select the build tab and click the advanced button to select the C# 7.2.

[image]

[image]

The other way is editing your csproj file. You can add `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` in the property group.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/12/08/async-main-is-available-but-hidden/

The Chinese version is https://lindexi.gitee.io/post/VisualStudio-%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E4%B8%89%E4%B8%AA%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E5%90%AF%E5%8A%A8%E6%9C%80%E6%96%B0-C-%E5%8A%9F%E8%83%BD.html

Or you should select the startup main.

[image]

Comment: ok thanks now when i change the version from c# 7.1 to c# 7.2 the error has gone. but i have notied that the code is not running in parallel, as calling the `grttingcustomerinfo` will be done in sequential manner... could the problem be in the way i am using the `throttler.Release();`??

Comment: It has not run as parallel for you have not to use multi-thread to do it. You should change `ipfd.companies.Select(c => gettingCustomerInfo(c.properties.website.value))` to `ipfd.companies.Select(c => Task.Run(()=>gettingCustomerInfo(c.properties.website.value)))`.

Comment: `but i have notied that the code is not running in paralle` @testtest That is a different question. Please write mark this answer as the answer, then write up a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing something like this to work around with the issue for a while.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AsyncTask().Wait();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ...
        }

    }

    static async Task AsyncTask()
    {
        ...
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();     
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(queryString, content);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public async void RunTask()
    {
        await SomeTask();
    }

    private Task<int> SomeTask()
    {
        var x = 10;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return Task.FromResult(x);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.RunTask();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes - lindexi answer was very good! I didn't know you could do that. Glad it's working for you now :).